# I am trying to filter through posts that are only assigned to categories to the homepage (Laravel)

Tags: php, database, laravel

I am using Laravel for a project, the website is a blog and I am having trouble with something. I want to pull through recent posts (articles) onto the homepage but only the ones that have been assigned a category but so far it's just pulling them all through.

here is my HomeController Index function

```
   public function index()
{
    $articles = article::all();
    $categories = categories::all();

    return view('submissions', ['submissions' => $articles
    ->filter(function($categories) {
        return $categories == 'Test Category';
    })]);


}
```

and here is my home blade view

```
@foreach($submissions as $post)
    <a id="recentposts" href="/articles/{{ $post->id }}/{{ $post->title 
    }}" title="{{ $post->title }}">{{ 
    $post->title }}</a><br/>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

As you can see I have tried using filter but doesn't same to work when trying to filter if another table is linked to another table (an article is linked to a category)

Hope all this makes sense to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = categories::with('articles')->all();

    return view('submissions', compact('categories'));
}
```

It will load all categories and articles attached to each category.

Alternatively, you could use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) method to load only articles with a category:

```
$articles = article::has('category')->all();
```

Comment: Yes, this works thank you! How would I go by it if I wanted to just pull through articles linked to a certain category, for example, all articles that are linked to a category called 'Weekly talk'

Comment: @Jake123 if you want to display all categories one by one with all their articles, use nested foreach. If you want to display just articles from one category, do something like this in the view: `@foreach ($categories->where('name', 'Weekly talk')->first()->articles as $article)`. Here you're working with loaded collection, so no new queries will be executed.

Comment: i get this error 'Trying to get property of non-object', code:     `@if (isset ($submissions))
                    @foreach ($submissions->where('title', 'Test Category')->first()->articles as $article)`

Comment: @Jake123 the error means that there is no submission with the title called 'Test Category'. You can do `{{ dd($submissions) }}` to check this.

Comment: nevermind, I was pulling through the articles instead of categories, that's why it was saying there was no category called 'Test Category', thank you for you help :)